# Optimal First Clear Route for Gragas?

Tags: league-of-legends

Gragas is making a huge comeback into the meta, and I've been getting some pretty good wins with him. So I want to know how I should go about my first clear so that I can get a good amount of gold while keeping me healthy enough for a gank. However, I prioritize farm over camping a lane, so please keep this in mind when giving me an answer. I use this setup, but if you think there's something I should change, let me know in your answer.

**Runes**    9 AS Reds   9 Flat Armor Yellows 9 Flat CDR Blues 3 AP Quints

**Masteries** 12/0/18 with Sorcery, DblEgSwrd, Natural Talent, and Oppressor

Recovery, Tough Skin, Runic Armor, Insight, Swiftness, and SotA

Note: I am asking for routes that give the maximum gold per minute while keeping me healthy enough for a gank, which I consider about 50% of my health. However, if there is a route that somehow allows for 2 full sweeps of the jungle without any regard for the lanes, I'll accept that too. At the time of this edit, we are heading into patch 6.5.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the best route for a Gragas with that set of Runes/Masteries, prioritizing the maximum gold/minute?

Comment: I think you should precise the patch in your question if someone read it in a month and later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally disagree with the choice of reds... Not because it's not helping your clear time (because it clearly is the set of red that will help the most your clear time) just because you are compromising your teamfight capabilities. I'd go with magic pen reds (or maybe even hybrid pen).

```
Starting items : Hunter's Talisman + 3 health pots.
```

(I don't think the flask is a good investment on Gragas because he already have natural sustain and his later clears are just dumb quick with Runic Echoes)

Something to keep in mind with gragas is that he's now really good at clearing camps AoE wise becasue of his new W. Blue buff start will always be better on gragas because he's not an AS champion to proc the krug stun often. So keeping this in mind...

If you want "the best route" to level 3, you should go :

```
Blue side start : Gromp (with leash and smite) -> Blue -> Red (smite)
Red side start : Krugs (with leash and smite) -> Red -> Blue (smite)
```

If you want "the best route" to level 4, you should go :

```
Blue side start : Gromp (with leash and smite) -> Blue -> wolves -> raptors -> Red (smite)
Red side start : Krugs (with leash and smite) -> Red -> raptors -> wolves -> Blue (smite)
```

If you don't plan on ganking at all during your first clear maybe doing the "last" camp before the last buff and smiting it for the buff could be an idea... Not sure since I'm not doing it usually.

Usually, I don't do a full level 4 clear, I try to maximize as much my health so I can gank early enough. So my personal first clear looks something like :

```
Blue side start : Gromp (with leash and smite it) -> Blue -> raptors -> Red (smite)
Red side start : Krugs (with leash and smite it) -> Red -> raptors -> Blue (smite)
```

Don't forget also that Gragas has a good Scuttle crab clear because of his Body Slam CC. (CC reduces the armor and MR of the scuttle crab) Not that this is something that should matter because it is extremely slow to do scuttle crab for the amount of XP it gives. (But you should still do it for map control and help you regen since it doesn't retaliate and gives you HP back)

Comment: Small caveat to the Scuttle crab clear, it provides phenomenal regen if you're falling behind on your first clear since it doesn't retaliate and you still get your bonuses from the Hunter's Talisman.

Comment: Completely agree, but since he was talking about an "optimal clear", I interpreted it as a "fastest clear" kind of approach. Added the clarification.

Comment: I personally prefer a very beefy Gragas over one that has mediocre damage onto the enemy ADC. Being able to fit 2 E's into a teamfight is just way more valuable to me than dying with 1 rotation and giving my team more damage onto a carry with lifesteal.

Comment: Flask is good on Gragas because you can upgrade it. Gragas does need mana regen a lot

Comment: I would suggest krug->raptor->scuttle(for hp)-> red (smite)->wolves->blue(smite) its a level 4 and half clear gets you boots and jungle item. this is greedy and not a ganking route.

Comment: But this path is really slow, with the level 3 and a half (the one I personally use), you get both buffs, and 90% of your HP for your first gank. And gragas firsts ganks are pretty deadly. Afterwards, usually, you have enough gold to buy your smite upgrade + boots.

Comment: @Oak Yeah... but Runic Echoes now take care itself of the mana issue. Flask is just not a great buy anymore.

Comment: IF you buy Runic Echoes. Tank Gragas benefits much more from %HP than ap

Comment: @Oak Yes but Runic Echoes is THAT good at the moment (it is also a huge part as of why gragas is piercing back). It'll give you burst for your early ganks and you can rotate back quickly to a traditionnal tank build right after.